# Dynamic navIconName ToolbarAndroid with react-native-vector-icon

Tags: android, react-native

I use `react-native-vector-icon`and I would like props `navIconName` change dynamically to have something like this:

```
import Icon, {ToolbarAndroid} from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

...
render() {

    const NAV_DRAWER_BUTTON = "menu";
    const NAV_BACK_BUTTON = "bluetooth"

    const ICON = this.props.navigationState.key == 'home'? NAV_DRAWER_BUTTON : NAV_BACK_BUTTON;

    return (
        <ToolbarAndroid
            navIconName={ICON}
            onIconClicked={this._onLogoSelected}
            style={styles.toolbar}
            subtitle={this.props.subtitle}
            title={this.props.title} />
    );
}
```

this works, but if, for example, I write `const NAV_BACK_BUTTON = "arrow_back"` I have a message which said to use icon from given list in message.
How to use my icon arrow_back?

Comment: Have you tried `md-arrow-back`? I've just read it on the react-native-vector-icons github page (section ToolbarAndroid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrow_back` should be `arrow-back`.

You can see list of all material icons here - https://materialicons.github.io/

Comment: Hum right I used https://material.io/icons and arrow navigation back is "arrow_back". Thanks